# Dynamically align TextView to next line in horizontal LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am adding `TextView` dynamically using for loop to `LinearLayout` which orientation is horizontal. Is it possible to align the `TextView` to second line if it reach end of screen width?

Comment: should give the weight for each textview

Comment: Why don't you try with vertical orientation.? Or if it is needed then use GridLayout or Tablet Layout with table row ..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will do the trick,

```
textview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in the following manner:

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout layout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        layout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            TextView lblView = new TextView(this);
            TextView lblView2 = new TextView(this);
            lblView.setLayoutParams(params);
            lblView.setText("hello");
            lblView.setEms(5);
            lblView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            lblView2.setLayoutParams(params);
            lblView2.setText("hello");
            lblView2.setEms(5);
            lblView2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            layout1.addView(lblView);
            layout2.addView(lblView2);
        }
        layout.addView(layout1);
        layout.addView(layout2);
        setContentView(layout);
```